# Delete duplicates strings from big array

Tags: javascript

How can I remove duplicates from 10.000 elements array of strings?

I have array of strings in format:

```
[ '[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]',
'[[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]', ....]
```

There are 10.000 of elements in it, and after deleting duplicates it should be about 500. For now i'm using this code, but it doesnt work since "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" problem is poping out.

```
newarr = [];

for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var idx = arr.indexOf(arr[i])
  while (idx != 0) {
    newarr.push(idx);
    idx = arr.indexOf(wycinki[i], idx + 1);
  }    
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @3piy array of Strings without duplicates

Answer (score 5):

A one-liner that can do it utilizes the Javascript [Set class.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
Array.from(new Set(arr));
```

This code will return an array of all unique strings.

Comment: very elegant solution